# Can we fix the grammar on the "possible duplicate" comment?

Tags: bug, comments, edits, duplicate-answers, wording

When closing a question as a dupe, the system generates a comment:

> possible duplicate of [Can we fix the grammar on the "possible duplicate" comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195481/can-we-fix-the-grammar-on-the-possible-duplicate-comment) -- [hexafraction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186121/hexafraction) [1 day ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195481/can-we-fix-the-grammar-on-the-possible-duplicate-comment)

Can we get a capital P and a period on this comment, please? I find myself editing the comment afterwards for two characters.

I know this is a nitpick, but it's still something that could be fixed.

Comment: @hims056 The irony :) I need to search better, sorry. VTCd as well.